# Dynamically Selecting a Javascript DOM Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a script that only works when the DOM element is selected (not the jQuery Object). However, I am unable to turn it on or off for more than one element.

**Here is the markup:**

```
<div class="tab-pane active">
  <div class="heading">
    <h1>Heading for Tab One</h1>
  </div>                  
  <p class="content" contenteditable="true">Editable Content when focused on</p>
</div> 
<div class="tab-pane active">
  <div class="heading">
    <h1>Heading for Tab Two</h1>
  </div>                  
  <p class="content" contenteditable="true">Editable Content when focused on</p>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane active">
  <div class="heading">
    <h1>Heading for Tab Three</h1>
  </div>                  
  <p class="content" contenteditable="true">Editable Content when focused on</p>
</div>
```

**Here is the script:**

```
//this works but only for the first paragraph
var input = $('p.content[contenteditable]')[0];
$(input).keypress(function(e){       
  var sel = window.getSelection();      
  var node = sel.anchorNode;
  //if ENTER was pressed while caret was inside the editable paragraph
    if(node.parentNode === input && e.keyCode === 13 ){        
    // prevent the browsers from inserting <div>, <p>, or <br> on their own
    e.preventDefault();
    // the caret position inside the node
    offset = sel.anchorOffset;
    // insert a '\n' character at that position
    text = node.textContent;
    textBefore = text.slice( 0, offset );
    textAfter = text.slice( offset ) || ' ';
    node.textContent = textBefore + '\n' + textAfter;

    // position the caret after that new-line character
    range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart( node, offset + 1 );
    range.setEnd( node, offset + 1 );

    // update the selection
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange( range );
    }
});
```

Why must I select the DOM object like this? And why won't the function work if I use `this` as the selector for the focused paragraph and `on` for the keypress event?

Why won't this work when dynamically selecting the paragraph based on `focus`:

```
$('p.content[contenteditable]').focus(function(){ 
 var input = $(this);   
  $(input).on('keypress',function(e){       
    var sel = window.getSelection();      
    var node = sel.anchorNode;
    //if ENTER was pressed while caret was inside the editable paragraph
      if(node.parentNode === input && e.keyCode === 13 ){        
      // prevent the browsers from inserting <div>, <p>, or <br> on their own
      e.preventDefault();
      // the caret position inside the node
      offset = sel.anchorOffset;
      // insert a '\n' character at that position
      text = node.textContent;
      textBefore = text.slice( 0, offset );
      textAfter = text.slice( offset ) || ' ';
      node.textContent = textBefore + '\n' + textAfter;

      // position the caret after that new-line character
      range = document.createRange();
      range.setStart( node, offset + 1 );
      range.setEnd( node, offset + 1 );

      // update the selection
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange( range );
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: It's almost always wrong to bind one event handler inside another one. Every time you focus on a paragraph you add another keypress handler, so you end up with multiple keypress handlers running.

Comment: Although I am not showing it here, I would turn event(s) `off()` on `blur`. I like to keep the code example as small as possible so future viewers can get answers without having to dig through unrelated code.

Comment: Why do you need to turn the event off? When the element doesn't have focus it won't receive keypress events, so there's no harm in having the handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the javascript DOM element was not needed after all. So the following code sufficed:

```
$('p.content[contenteditable]').keypress(function(e){       
  var sel = window.getSelection();      
  var node = sel.anchorNode;
  //if ENTER was pressed while caret was inside the editable paragraph
    if(e.keyCode === 13 ){        
    // prevent the browsers from inserting <div>, <p>, or <br> on their own
    e.preventDefault();
    // the caret position inside the node
    offset = sel.anchorOffset;
    // insert a '\n' character at that position
    text = node.textContent;
    textBefore = text.slice( 0, offset );
    textAfter = text.slice( offset ) || ' ';
    node.textContent = textBefore + '\n' + textAfter;

    // position the caret after that new-line character
    range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart( node, offset + 1 );
    range.setEnd( node, offset + 1 );

    // update the selection
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange( range );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that it is a bad idea to bind an event handler (in your case `keypress`), on every focus action. Better do it apart:

```
var focused;

$('p.content[contenteditable]').on('focus', function() {
  focused = this;
});

$('p.content[contenteditable]').on("keypress", function(e){     
  var sel = window.getSelection();      
  var node = sel.anchorNode;
  //if ENTER was pressed while caret was inside the editable paragraph
    if(node.parentNode === focused && e.keyCode === 13 ){        
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('HEY!');
      //do stuff
    }
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/67q4tve0/3/).

Comment: Yes, that does indeed work. However, I think I am going out of my mind because when used with the additional code (the code that replaces the _do stuff_ comment), it does not work. The _do stuff_ code has been added. Is there anything in there that would prevent this from working? Again, it works perfectly when the selector is the javascript DOM element but not when it is a Jquery object. Ultimately, I am preventing tags like `div`, `p`, and `br` from being added when enter is pressed and instead adding a `\n` so that I can save the changes to a database.